# Passed data to custom email view is not avaliable

Tags: php, laravel-4

As you know, send a email via laravel is so simple as:

```
// setting data
$data = array(
    'band' => 'Kings of leon'
);

// send email    
\Mail::send('emails.activation', $data , function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

Then in  `/app/views/emails/activation.blade.php` view could contains a not complicated structure:

```
My fav band is {{ $band }}. Here a logo:

<img src="{{ $message->embed('/img/logo_small.png') }}" alt="">
```

Views path:

> **/app/config/views.php**
>
> 'paths' => array(**DIR**.'/../views', ),

Everything above works like a champ. However, if you change the email view from `emails.activation` to another one belonging in different path from default cause two problem:

- The `$message` var is not longer available in the view
- The `$data` arg is not passed to the view.

So, lets see:

```
// setting data
$data = array(
    'band' => 'Kings of leon'
);

// send email using different view outside of default path
\Mail::send('theme::views.emails.activation', $data , function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

The view is successfully found, but when it is compiled throws two exception stating `undefined var: $message` and `undefined var: $band`.

am I missing an extra-configuration? or is it a bug? Thank you.

### update

After an exhaustive revision, the problem resided in a calling of the email view twice in the same controller, for example:

```
$stringLocation = \Theme::getViewLocation('emails.activation');

... more stuff here 

\Mail::send($stringLocation, $data , function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

So, calling `getViewLocation()` compiled the view, and of course, the data were not present at this exact point. My bad was believe that the error was in `\Mail::send` line than `getViewLocation`.

Comment: How do you change this path for `/app/config/views.php` ? The one you showed is the same as default. Second thing is that you use probably https://github.com/teepluss/laravel4-theme and this package might cause this problem

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek, 1: I did not change the view path, I just only exposed it in order to clarify my current config. 2: yes! Actually that package manage my themes, but, I do not understand, because I only passed the view path ass a "string", this should not affect.

Comment: Does it affect only template used for emails or all templates even if you don't send an email?

Comment: It only affects views used for emails. The rest of views work perfect

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek, sorry for my bad, take a look the edited question. Thank you for your help. Have a good day